# Countdown HIIT timer Restarting timer

Tags: java, android, timer

I am making a countdown timer in the fashion of a HIIT timer with an 'active' and 'rest' period that will repeat any number of times. I have the two timers running, but in my loop to restart the timers, when I call this.start it starts both timers.

When I click on this.start in Android studio, it highlights both .start() calls, I want to to only start the .start above 'intervals--'

How can I start only the first one again?

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    minutesText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minutesText);
    secondsText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondsText);
    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    intervalCount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.intervalCount);






    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (minutesText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                minutesInt = 0;
            } else {
                minutesString = minutesText.getText().toString();
                minutesInt = Integer.parseInt(minutesString);

            }

            secondsString = secondsText.getText().toString();
            if (secondsText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                secondsInt = 0;

            } else {
                secondsString = secondsText.getText().toString();
                secondsInt = Integer.parseInt(secondsString);

            }
            if (intervalCount.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                intervals = 0;
            } else {
                intervalsString = intervalCount.getText().toString();
                intervals = Integer.parseInt(intervalsString);
            }


            final int timerAmount = ((minutesInt * 60) + (secondsInt)) * 1000;



                Log.i("Hello, ", "intervals are " + intervals);
                new CountDownTimer(timerAmount, 1000) {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        activeRunning = true;
                        String timeLeft = String.format("%02d : %02d",
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))
                        );
                        textView.setText("Reamining: " + timeLeft);
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {

                        textView.setText("FINISHED1");


                        try {
                            Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
                            r.play();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                restRunning = true;
                                activeRunning = false;
                                String timeLeft = String.format("%02d : %02d",
                                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))
                                );
                                textView.setText("Rest: " + timeLeft);
                            }
                            public void onFinish() {
                                restRunning = false;

                                textView.setText("FINISHED2");
                                try {
                                    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                                    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
                                    r.play();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }


                            }
                        }.start();

                            if (intervals > 0) {
                                intervals--;
                                this.start();
                            }
                    }
                }.start();
                    intervals--;

            }






    });


}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the second timer nested in the brackets of the first? That could be the reason...

Comment: It is, but I figured it had to be since it runs after the first timer is completed. It's nested in the onFinish of the first timer